# Authentication error in Spreadsheet script : ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with a script of type standard linked to a GCP project that received  all scopes available in the standard list for Sheet, Drive and Mail.

I manually added the following scopes to the OAuth consent section :
.../auth/script.deployments
.../auth/script.deployments.readonly

Still, when I call the API from the spreadsheet's script, I get the error response below.

```
  const {
    version = 1,
    id = ScriptApp.getScriptId(),
    token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    page = "",
    size = 50,
    type = "WEB_APP",
  } = options;

  const uri = `https://script.googleapis.com/v${version}/projects/${id}/deployments`;

  const fullURI = `${uri}?pageSize=${size}${page ? `&pageToken=${page}` : ""}`;

  const params = {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "get",
  };

  const deps = [];

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fullURI, params);
```

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.apps.script.management.v1.DeploymentsService.ListDeployments",
          "service": "script.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I followed Tanaike's advice and created a library linked to a `standard` GCP project that has the Script API enabled.

I moved the code that calls the API (https://script.googleapis.com) to the library and I linked the library to my spreadsheet project (`default` GCP project).

When I run the code from within the library itself, it works but when I call it from my spreadsheet's project, it fails with

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Apps Script API has not been used in project 148191949068 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script.googleapis.com/overview?project=148191949068 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script.googleapis.com/overview?project=148191949068"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "script.googleapis.com",
          "consumer": "projects/148191949068"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried the "url" hyperlink but the page says I need additional access (note that this is my domain and the user I use is admin).

I could change my spreadsheet's project from `default`to `standard`and give it the appropriate oauthScopes but that is a nightmare as you discover which scopes you need mostly when your code breaks...

First of all, am I the only one to find that `default` and `standard` are confusing as terminology (I am not a native English speaker so that might influence my perception).

Then, how can I solve this please ?

Finally, am I the only one to find that it's time to search for an alternative to Google Workspace ?  The whole thing has become overly complicated IMHO.

Comment: It works, however, if I add the following to the appscript.json file of the spreadsheet's project :   "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments"].  This is not entirely satisfactory as I may have to add more scopes as I call other libraries that require more scopes.

Comment: To clarify, the enabled APIs in your project are the Apps Script API, Google Drive API, and Gmail API. Would that be correct? Also, what were the scopes that you manually added in the appsscript.json?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Saddles The APIs enabled through the addition of services in the code editor are Drive and GMail.  You cannot enable a Script Service.  In order to enable the Script API, you have to turn your project from ```default```to ```standard```and modify the appscript.json by adding the required oauth scopes.  What a mess !

Answer (score 1):

From your following comment,

> It works, however, if I add the following to the appscript.json file of the spreadsheet's project : `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments"]`. This is not entirely satisfactory as I may have to add more scopes as I call other libraries that require more scopes.

In this case, as a workaround, how about adding the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments` from a temporal library? By this, you can automatically add other scopes to your main Google Apps Script project without updating `appsscript.json`. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

#### 1. Create a Google Apps Script project

Please create a Google Apps Script project. In this case, you can create a standalone type.

#### 2. Add a scope

Please add a scope to `appsscript.json` by adding `"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments"]`.

#### 3. Deploy as library

Please deploy the Google Apps Script project as a library. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#create_and_share_a_library)

Please copy the script ID. This script ID is used with your main Google Apps Script project.

#### 4. Install a library

Please install the library with the copied script ID. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project)

By this flow, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments` is added to your main Google Apps Script project without updating `appsscript.json`.

Comment: I do not doubt this would work but...  I use a library to link three spreadsheets : orders, delivery rounds and load plan.  Articles ordered are copied to load plan and customers to the delivery route.  Three weeks ago, on a busy Monday, the library stopped working (file read error was the message).  It came back on 3 PM.  I assume it was a problem on Google's side as I did not do anything to fix the situation.  This is why I am looking at implementing doGet directly in the Orders spreadsheet and replicate what the library does (at least vital functions).

Comment: @ballatom Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. But, if my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Don't worry about your English, it seems good enough for waht we are doing here.